# On normal matrix svd.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a normal matrix with SVD $A=USU'$ where $S$ is diagonal non-negative real then is $A$ a diagonal matrix?

It seems true for symmetric matrices but normality is stronger.

Comment: Every symmetric matrix is normal. There are non diagonal symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 1):

No, but $A$ is self-adjoint (or symmetric if real). Note that a normal matrix is one for which $A^*A=AA^*$. It is diagonalizable (the matrix $S$) with an orthonormal basis of eigen vectors (the matrix $U$). The statement is that if $S$ is real, then $A$ was in fact symmetric/self-adjoint $A=A^*$ (I don't think being non-negative enters here?).